# Laravel - Valet 2.* only returns 'it works!'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, nginx, homebrew

I'm trying to setup Valet to use with my Laravel projects, but ran into the problem mentioned in the title. The current version of Valet I'm running is 2.0.3.

So far this is what I've tried:

- Reinstalled valet + restart
- Reinstalled php7.0 --with-fpm
- Restarted **nginx**
- Updated composer global
- Installed and ran **mysql** through brew
- Installed and started **dnsmasq**
- Restarted all services + started all services via **Brew**
- Parked valet in different folders, but getting the same 'it works!'

I've looked at other people with the same problem, but they seem to run Valet 1.*. The solutions for them does not work for me. I don't get any error messages, and pinging **foo.dev** work as you would expect.

Really appreciate any feedback which can help me resolve this problem.

Comment: try to `valet stop` `valet uninstall` and then try reinstall again.

Answer (score 2):

Check `apachectl` status. Stop `apachectl` using `sudo apachectl stop`.
Then run:
`valet install`
After run:
`valet restart`

Answer (score 1):

I had a different problem where i stopped nginx and then started it manualy, "it works" now. lol

sudo nginx -s stop

sudo nginx

Answer (score 0):

Before upgrading to this version you should run the following commands to stop and uninstall the existing Caddy daemon as they have said in the [documentation](https://github.com/cpriego/valet-linux):

```
valet stop
valet uninstall
```

and then

```
valet install
valet restart
```

Comment: Tried this, but still gives the same 'it works!' result.

Answer (score 0):

I did not manage to fix the issue on the computer where the problem originated. However, I did manage to get it running on a *clean* macOS Sierra install, following the guide provided by the Laravel documentation.

Here are the steps I followed in order:

1. Installed **Homebrew**
2. Followed [this](https://developerjack.com/blog/2016/08/26/Installing-PHP71-with-homebrew/) guide to install **php v7.1**
3. Then followed [this](https://gist.github.com/nrollr/3f57fc15ded7dddddcc4e82fe137b58e) guide to both install and setup **mysql**
4. Installed **Valet** via composer
5. Ran the `valet install` command

   - This installed both **nginx** and **dnsmasq**
6. Ran the `valet park` in my workspace folder

I can now run **example-project.dev** in the browser and it will load the project just as the command `php artisan serve`.

**Note:** on the computer where the problem originated, both MAMP and XAMP were installed, but not currently running as I tested valet. There might have been config or installation clashes that made this not work as expected.

Hopefully this will help someone in the same situation.