# Laravel Valet doesn't report errors but I can't see my Laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, macos-high-sierra, laravel-valet

First, I'm running macOS High Sierra, with Homebrew's PHP 7.1

I've also followed the Valet documentation to the letter, as well as trying what was on these asks: [Valet (Laravel): DNS address can not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172691/valet-laravel-dns-address-can-not-be-found/37174256?noredirect=1#answer-37174256) and [Laravel valet It works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708139/laravel-valet-it-works) aaaaaand, despite all of that, when I navigate to project.dev, I just get "It works!" I was having issues pinging, but that turned out to be Stealth Mode in the macOS Firewall.

I have Laravel set up in this directory, so I SHOULD be getting the default splash page, right?

Also, in case it matters, here's the line I used to install PHP 7.1 itself: `brew install php71 --with-httpd --with-pear --with-postgresql --with-thread-safety --with-homebrew-curl`

Comment: Can you check if your php.ini is set to display errors?
`display_errors = On`

Comment: @tintinboss I do have Errors set to display `E_ALL` and no errors are in my command line or my browser.

Comment: display `E_ALL` and `display_error = On` are not the same constant on php.ini 

I'd still suggest to check that.

Comment: @tintinboss I did already; I apologize for not being clear.  `display_errors` is set to `On` and the level is set to `E_ALL`.

Comment: Ahh! I think your nginx virtual host is not set!
Did you follow this ? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/valet#serving-sites

Also try `link` as described in docs. Make sure your site is on default directory `~/Sites/..`

Comment: Also, make sure your in built apache2 server (High Sierra) is stopped by running `apachectl stop` followed by a `valet restart` . Worth a try

Comment: Done, done, and done, and I've been running `valet restart` after I try anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157830/discussion-between-tintinboss-and-janet).

Answer (score 1):

You should check your settings related to firewall. Make sure you are allowing pings and ICMP.

To check it on a Mac :

> System Preference > Security & Privacy > Firewall > Firewall Options

Comment: That takes care of the ping issue, but I'm still not seeing the Laravel splash :(  (But hey, progress is progress, especially at 2am!)

Comment: This could be related to your precompiled files. Let's delete compiled.php inside vendor folder and run `composer update` from the command line.If that works i will edit my asnwer according to this. If not we try to come up with another solution.

Comment: Alrighty, nuked /vendor and ran `composer update`, restarted valet, and, just to insure that caching wasn't kicking my rear end again, I opened a Private tab and went to project.dev again and "It Works" >.<

Comment: Did you check services list with brew? `> brew services list` command will show you services. Some might be stopped.

Comment: php71 nginx and dnsmasq are all running.  (Character limit prevents me from pasting the full output of that command.)  httpd is also specifically listed as stopped.  All 3 services are running as root; is that a problem?

Comment: I really can't point out  the problem since you tried trobleshootings. But i can suggest you to follow this answers guides,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42976841/4465062 Maybe you are missing some steps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157784/discussion-between-atilla-arda-acikgoz-and-janet).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the Apache that comes pre-installed with macos is running in the port 80. Before starting valet, make sure that Apache is stopped.

You can these commands: `sudo apachectl stop` or `sudo apachectl -k stop` to stop Apache, and after that, then you can proceed with your valet process.

Hope it helps.